# BC30108: 'Date' is a type and cannot be used as an expression in aspx.net

Tags: asp.net

> Line 6:    Line 7:      <%    Line 8:   Response.Write "
>
> The
>   function Now returns: " & Now & "
>
> " Line 9:   Line 10:
>     Response.Write "
>
> The function Date returns: " & Date & "
>
> "
>
> Compiler Error Message: BC30800: Method arguments must be enclosed in
>   parentheses.

I am using Simple Notepad text file for execution.
I am working on ASP.NET first time and i have at starting level.

Comment: Can you try calling `Date()`?

Answer (score 0):

You write it like this:

```
<%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %>
<br />
<br />
<%= "The function Date returns " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() %>
```

Comment: Thanks Brother VDWWD